# Explaining differences between the folder texmf and texmf-texlive in Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, texmf

I have only downloaded a bibtex utility to export the bib entries that cited in the TeX documents. It contains `.dtx` and `.ins`, but the instructions is not really clear enough to install it into my system (Ubuntu 12.04). I have to locate `/usr/share` and find that there are two folders inside. They are `/usr/share/texmf/` and `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/`. I have ever installed additional packages in TeX, so I know the way to update TeX sysem. But in order to add a new utility, I don't know which one of them is better. Currently, I don't see the folder `utils` in both.

Could you give me an advice to install the util bibexport please? Any suggestion will always be appreciated.

Comment: What version of TeX Live do you have? 2009 or 2012? The `bibexport` bundle should be available with one of the provided (Debian) packages for TeX Live 2012 (`texlive-bibtex-extra`)

Comment: You may also use your 'personal' tex directory, which will be `~/texmf` (test with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`).  Just make sure that the subfolders of `texmf` mimic the structure of your 'system' tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debian (and Ubuntu) TeX Live 2009 ships its files in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`, which is a merge of the upstream (TeX Live) directories `texmf-dist` and `texmf`.

In Debian (and Ubuntu) `/usr/share/texmf` is used for packages other than the texlive-* packages.

In Debian (and Ubuntu) TeX Live 2012 the directory layout has changed and is now `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`, `/usr/share/texlive/texmf` matching upstream layout, and as before `/usr/share/texmf` for packages outside of texlive.

If you want to install additional package, I recommend using `/usr/local/share/texmf` instead, as is is the most approriate place.